# Обязательные поля и activeInput?

Tags: yii2

вот так в модели у меня отмечены обязательные поля

```
public function rules()

    {
            return [
                [['user_id', 'city_id', 'payment',], 'required'],
                 ['street', 'required', 'message' => 'Укажите название улицы.'],
        ...
       }
```

таким образом я организую работу с формой

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::activeLabel($model,'street'); ?>
                <?= Html::activeInput('text',$model,'street',['class'=>'form-control']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Собственно весь вопрос в том как можно при использовании `activeinput` отметить обязательные поля, учитывая что эти поля обязательные в модели. Использовать `Activeform` возможности нет

Answer (score 0):

Можете добавить html атрибут **required**, для полей, которые в вашей форме должны быть обязательными для заполнения

`<?= Html::activeInput('text',$model,'street',['class'=>'form-control', 'required' => true]) ?>`

Comment: не помогало. Отправка все равно происходила